# Aggregating tasks by duration for each day in a week/month? (PoSH)

Tags: powershell, grouping, pivot-table

I am parsing JSON from a web service to get my tasks (using a TimeFlip).  Right now, I get back each task, when it occurred, and duration, so the data looks like this:

```
(taskname, start, durationinSec)
TaskA,"6/5/2018 12:16:36 PM",312
TaskB,"6/5/2018 12:30:36 PM",200
TaskA,"6/6/2018 08:00:00 AM",150
TaskA,"6/6/2018 03:00:00 PM",150
(etc etc)
```

I would like to generate a rollup report, showing by day which tasks had how much time.

While the data will span weeks, I'm just trying to do a weekly report that I can easily transcribe into our time app (since they won't give me an API key).  So I'll do something like `where {$_.start -gt (? {$_.start -gt (get-date -Hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00).adddays(-7)}` first.

```
       6/5/2018    6/6/2018
 TaskA 312         300
 TaskB 200
```

How can I do that?  I assume group-object, but unclear how you'd do either the pivot or even the grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for `PowerShell` and `Pivot` I found this  [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/andyoakley/1651859) with a more universal way to create the PivotTable.
To transpose (swap x,y) you simply change the variables `$rotate`, `$keep`
It has the additional benefit of calculating a row Total

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\09\PivotTable.ps1
## Source https://gist.github.com/andyoakley/1651859
# #############################################################################
# Rotates a vertical set similar to an Excel PivotTable 
# #############################################################################
$OutputFile = "MyPivot.csv"

$data = @'
taskname,start,duration
TaskA,"6/5/2018 12:16:36 PM",312
TaskB,"6/5/2018 12:30:36 PM",200
TaskA,"6/6/2018 08:00:00 AM",150
TaskA,"6/6/2018 03:00:00 PM",150
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv |Select-Object taskname, duration, @{n='start';e={($_.start -split ' ')[0]}}

# Fields of interest
$rotate = "taskname"  # Bits along the top
$keep   = "start"     # Those along the side
$value  = "duration"  # What to total

#-------------------- No need to change anything below ------------------------

# Creatre variable to store the output
$rows = @()

# Find the unique "Rotate" [top row of the pivot] values and sort ascending
$pivots = $data | select -unique $rotate | foreach { $_.$rotate} | Sort-Object

# Step through the original data...
#  for each of the "Keep" [left hand side] find the Sum of the "Value" for each "Rotate"

$data | 
    group $keep  | 
    foreach { 
        $group = $_.Group 
        # Create the data row and name it as per the "Keep"
        $row = new-object psobject
        $row | add-member NoteProperty $keep $_.Name 
        # Cycle through the unique "Rotate" values and get the sum
        foreach ($pivot in $pivots) {
            $row | add-member NoteProperty $pivot ($group | where { $_.$rotate -eq $pivot } | measure -sum $value).Sum
        }
        # Add the total to the row
        $row | add-member NoteProperty Total ($group | measure -sum $value).Sum
        # Add the row to the collection 
        $rows += $row
    } 

# Do something with the pivot rows
$rows | Format-Table
$rows | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
start    TaskA TaskB Total
-----    ----- ----- -----
6/5/2018   312   200   512
6/6/2018   300         300
```

Or x/y swapped

```
taskname 6/5/2018 6/6/2018 Total
-------- -------- -------- -----
TaskA         312      300   612
TaskB         200            200
```

Comment: Cool! I'll try this out today.

Answer (score 5):

The following doesn't output a pivot table, but performs **the desired grouping and aggregation**:

```
$rows = @'
taskname,start,durationinSec
TaskA,"6/5/2018 12:16:36 PM",312
TaskB,"6/5/2018 12:30:36 PM",200
TaskA,"6/6/2018 08:00:00 AM",150
TaskA,"6/6/2018 03:00:00 PM",150
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$rows | Group-Object { (-split $_.start)[0] }, taskname | ForEach-Object {
  $_ | Select-Object @{ n='Date'; e={$_.Values[0]} }, 
                     @{ n='Task'; e={$_.Values[1]} }, 
                     @{ n='Duration'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object durationInSec -Sum).Sum } } 
}
```

`(-split $_.start)[0]` splits each `start` value by whitespace and returns the first token (`[0]`), which is the *date portion* of the time stamp; e.g., `6/5/2018` is returned for `6/5/2018 12:16:36 PM`; passing this operation as a script block (`{ ... }`) to `Group-Object` means that grouping happens by date only, not also time (in addition to grouping by `taskname`).

This yields:

```
Date     Task  Duration
----     ----  --------
6/5/2018 TaskA      312
6/5/2018 TaskB      200
6/6/2018 TaskA      300
```

---

To construct **pivot-table-like output** requires substantially more effort, and it won't be fast:

Assume that `$objs` contains the objects created above (`$objs = $rows | Group-Object ...`).

```
# Get all distinct dates.
$dates = $objs | Select-Object -Unique -ExpandProperty Date
# Get all distinct tasks.
$tasks = $objs | Select-Object -Unique -ExpandProperty Task

# Create an ordered hashtable that contains an entry for each task that
# holds a nested hashtable with (empty-for-now) entries for all dates.
$ohtPivot = [ordered] @{}
$tasks | ForEach-Object {
  $ohtDates = [ordered] @{}
  $dates | ForEach-Object { $ohtDates[$_] = $null }
  $ohtPivot[$_] = $ohtDates
}

# Fill the hashtable from the grouped objects with the task- and 
# date-specific durations.
$objs | ForEach-Object { $ohtPivot[$_.Task][$_.Date] = $_.Duration }

# Output the resulting hashtable in pivot-table-like form by transforming
# each entry into a custom object
$ohtPivot.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{ Task = $_.Key } | Add-Member -PassThru -NotePropertyMembers $_.Value
}
```

The above yields:

```
Task  6/5/2018  6/6/2018
----  --------  --------
TaskA      312      300
TaskB      200
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing with that split?

Comment: so it's basically `$_.start.split(' ')[0]` or `($_.start -split '\s')[0]` shorthand, neat

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: In this case, yes, but the unary form of `-split` has additional magic built in: trimming of leading and trailing whitespace also and splitting by any nonempty run of whitespace; in essence, it splits the same way that `awk` does by default.